# How to use WPF window as a messagebox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a small window with some style. Now i want to use it as exactly like a MessageBox. How can i achieve it?

Edit: I am new to WPF. I tried calling it in the main window like this.

```
Window1 messageBox = new Window1();
messageBox.Show();
messageBox.Activate();
```

The problem is the newly generated window disappears just behind main window without letting me to click on the action button in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` method to popup the messagebox window. In this way user will hve to first close the popup or message box window before moving back to main window

```
 MessageWindow message= new MessageWindow();
 message.ShowDialog();
```

**Edit**

You obviously would like to have result back in the main windows right? you can do it in several ways. One simplest way could be to expose a public method in MainWindow

```
public GetResult(bool result)
{
   //your logic
}
```

Create a constructor of MessageWindow that take MainWindow in parameter

```
 private MainWindow window;
 public MessageWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            window = mainWindow;
        }
   //now handle the click event of yes and no button
  private void YesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            //close this window
            this.Close();
            //pass true in case of yes
            window.GetResult(true);
        }

        private void NoButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //close this window
            this.Close();
            //pass false in case of no
            window.GetResult(false);
        }
 //in that case you will show the popup window like this
 MessageWindow message= new MessageWindow(this);
 message.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot... I have yes and no button in the dialogue box how can retrieve the value and apply the logic for it?

IF
    messageBox bool value = 1
    DO THIS
ELSE
    DO THIS

END DO

Comment: BTW I want to call it from User control. can you show me how?

Comment: post a separate question for it